# Container decoration is not visible when inside a column or row

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am newbie in flutter and i want to show the image with full width at the top after AppBar i got the code from stack-overflow and it is working fine if i put the container inside the body of Scaffold it is showing me the image with full width along the screen but when i put this code inside the column or row it is not visible .

i have tried to show the image inside the Image() class but it doesn't adjust according to screen size. i mean it is not responsive.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData queryData;
    queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                bannerImage(),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class bannerImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new DecoratedBox(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new AssetImage("images/banner.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I created separate widget for a bannerImage. kindly suggest me how i show my image with full width of screen or how i can show container without defining the child.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please explain what you are trying to show on the screen.
When you add a column, it will place the widgets vertically and you have added a row as the only element on the screen.
When you add row, you would want to add multiple widgets placed horizontally to each other.
I recommend you to read this article to understand the layouts properly - https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

Answer (score 0):

put `DecoratedBox` inside a container and give height and width.

Comment: I already try that but it is not working plus if i give the width and height it will be not responsive according to device.

Comment: This should be comment not an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: ExactAssetImage('images/flowers.jpeg'),
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: 8.0,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Use this container in your Column().

Answer (score 0):

First of all What you want is not clear and also you can't use  `queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);` directly you have to wrap with  MaterialApp/WidgetsApp widget.

You have to set child of `DecoratedBox`  to show image and also need to Wrap `Expanded bannerImage`.  below are some code from you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Streams Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: SecondRoute());
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: bannerImage()),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class bannerImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new DecoratedBox(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new NetworkImage("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGTVf63Vm3XgOncMVSOy0-jSxdMT8KVJIc8WiWaevuWiPGe0Pm"),
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          ),
        ), child: Text('dddsfdff dfdfds dfgfdgfg fdgfdddsfdff dfdfds dfgfdgfg fdgfdddsfdff dfdfds dfgfdgfg fdgfdddsfdff dfdfds dfgfdgfg fdgfdddsfdff dfdfds dfgfdgfg fdgfdddsfdff dfdfds dfgfdgfg fdgfdddsfdff dfdfds dfgfdgfg fdgfdddsfdff dfdfds dfgfdgfg fdgf'),);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you put so much text ddffffddfffdf in order to increase the size of the container but i want it to be increase without defining the child of container. what i want is to show the image at the top without text.

Comment: Do you wan to display image full size ? Have u tried to remove dfff.. text ? what output will display ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the Image code with a Container Widget that has its height and width specified, helps Container() and Row() to have your image displayed. Rows display images when they have width (double) value specified in Container() child within them, while Container() displays when a height (double) value is specified. I simply wrapped your image in a Container() widget within the Row() children and specified width and height double values. Feel free to adjust values to suit the ratio dimensions of your actual image. Hope this guide helps you on your project.

Replace the Row() widget with the below Code:

```
    Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 100.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: bannerImage(),
                          ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```